# Replace multiple characters in one line VBA

Tags: vba, replace

I am working in VBA and have a cell with all the letters of the alphabet, and I want to replace all the letters (with nothing, "", or a numeric, "0"), as well as possible punctuation. I currently run it as:

```
val = Replace(val, "(", "")
val = Replace(val, "]", "")
val = Replace(val, "A", "")
val = Replace(val, "B", "")
val = Replace(val, "C", "")
val = Replace(val, "D", "")
val = Replace(val, "E", "")
val = Replace(val, "F", "")
val = Replace(val, "G", "")
val = Replace(val, "H", "")
val = Replace(val, "I", "")
val = Replace(val, "J", "")
val = Replace(val, "K", "")
val = Replace(val, "L", "")
val = Replace(val, "M", "")
val = Replace(val, "N", "")
val = Replace(val, "O", "")
val = Replace(val, "P", "")
val = Replace(val, "Q", "")
val = Replace(val, "R", "")
val = Replace(val, "S", "")
val = Replace(val, "T", "")
val = Replace(val, "V", "")
val = Replace(val, "W", "")
val = Replace(val, "X", "")
val = Replace(val, "Y", "")
val = Replace(val, "Z", "")
```

I tried:

```
val = Replace(val, "(", "")
val = Replace(val, "]", "")
val = Replace(val, "[A-TV-Z]", "")
```

I could add a loop, but then the computation time will not change.

But it does not work. Is there a way to replace the 25 lines of code with a single line, as I tried, as I have to read through 1M cells, and it takes a long time to run currently. The sad part is, this replacement is run on separate occasions throughout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using regex.  I can't get this on single line but it should be quicker than your current version and has fewer lines.  Note you'll need a reference to the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions library.

```
Public Function Replacement(sInput) As String

Dim regex As New RegExp

With regex
   .Global = True
   .IgnoreCase = False
End With

regex.pattern = "[A-Z, a-z]"
Replacement = regex.Replace(sInput, "")


End Function
```

Comment: this worked, I just needed to add functionality from the VBA board. Tools  references and checked both     Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 1.0
Microsoft and VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

Comment: @alex just one of the two references is needed, or you can use late binding instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556910/how-do-i-get-regex-support-in-excel-via-a-function-or-custom-function

Answer (score 2):

The `Regex.Replace()` function is required to use regular expressions:

```
val = Replace(val, "(", "")
val = Replace(val, "]", "")
val = Regex.Replace(val, "[a-z]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```