# How to replace values in a string with values getting edited in between

Tags: vba, excel

I want to edit a string that contains the following:

From

```
WEEK = '2'
Date_Number(3,4,5,6,7,8)
AND
Allowance='100'
AND
((End_Date<'2017-09-17 00:00:00'
AND

Saturday_Name)
```

to

```
WEEK = '2'
Date_Number(22,25,27,28,29)
AND
Allowance='100'
AND
((End_Date<'2017-09-17 00:00:00'
AND

Saturday_Name)
```

I am already thinking of using split string using multiple delimiters ('Date_Number(' and ')') but the problem would be the other ')' will be also be splitted into an array. Is there a way that I could get or even edit the value between it?

Comment: the third parameter is the limit `Split(string, ")", 2)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f. RegEx is another option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: Your answer works! Although the problems is I have to edit other similar text but different placement on the string. The Date_Number might be placed on the 5th row or any row for that matter. The limit will be non-compliant by that sequence

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but you can try this pattern [`Date_Number\(.*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/w0UVeC)

```
Sub test()
    Dim str As String
    str = "WEEK = '2' ..."

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "Date_Number\(.*\)"
        str = .Replace(str, "Date_Number(22,25,27,28,29)")
    End With
End Sub
```

[How do I get regex support in excel via a function, or custom function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556910/how-do-i-get-regex-support-in-excel-via-a-function-or-custom-function)

Comment: How do you execute with statements? It gives me an error saying that "activex component can't create object vba"

Comment: @MarcoM it should be in a Sub or Function