# Add regular expression reference before running the macro vba

Tags: vba, excel

code :

```
Public Sub CallDeleteAllText(control As IRibbonControl)
Call LeaveNumbers
End Sub

Public Function PullOnly(strSrc As String, CharType As String)
Dim RE As RegExp
Dim regexpPattern As String
Set RE = New RegExp
CharType = LCase(CharType)
Select Case CharType
    Case Is = "digits":
        regexpPattern = "\D"
    Case Is = "letters":
        regexpPattern = "\d"
    Case Else:
        regexpPattern = ""
End Select
RE.Pattern = regexpPattern
RE.Global = True
PullOnly = RE.Replace(strSrc, "")
End Function

Sub LeaveNumbers()
Dim cCell As Range
For Each cCell In Selection
    If cCell <> "" Then
        cCell.Value = "'" & PullOnly(cCell.Text, "digits")
    End If
Next cCell
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = .Value
End With
End Sub
```

This code removes all text from the cell and leave all the numbers. But for this code to run, the user has to manually add `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions` reference from `Tools > References`. Is there a way to add the reference within the code itself so that, first it adds the reference and then removes all the text?

Comment: Use late binding instead: `Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556910/how-do-i-get-regex-support-in-excel-via-a-function-or-custom-function)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I added your code. I changed `Set RE = New RegExp` to `Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")`. Now, when I run it, it gives me error in line `Dim RE As RegExp`. The error is : `User-defined type not defined`.

Comment: `Dim RE As Object` as shown in my link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change these two lines of regex declaration and assignment in the PullOnly function to static late binding.

```
Dim RE As RegExp
...
Set RE = New RegExp

'becomes,

static RE As object
...
if re is nothing then Set RE = createobject("VBScript.RegExp")
```

Static vars are 'remembered' by the sub procedure or function where they are declared. Normally, RE would be 'forgotten' (and destructed) when the function was completed and exited. However, with a static RE, the second time (and all subsequent times) the function is entered it 'remembers' that it has already been set to a regex scripting object so it is unnecessary to set it again.

This does not mean that a static var is globally public; it is only available within the function or sub procedure where it was declared.

Comment: Yeah I am doing it, just getting a msg as `You can accept an answer in 3 minutes`. WIll wait for 3 minutes then will do it

Comment: Just a note for everyone else, the **static** natrue of RE means that it is only created once. Subsequent calls to the function skip the CreateObject call. This vastly improves run-time especially so when used in a UDF down a long column.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'll research for it more, didn't fully understand it though. :P